# Choose Woocommerce shipping method before address entry with postcode restriction

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am restricting delivery methods based on some UK postcodes on Woocommerce, but that means the delivery options are disabled until an address is entered. The message that is displayed is:

**There are no shipping methods available. Please double check your address, or contact us if you need any help.**

Once an accepted postcode is entered only then a selection appears with choice of shipping methods.

Is there a way to show shipping methods without entering any address and use the postcode restriction at the same time.
I can't find any settings to overcome this.

Comment: The only way should be to [override the WooCommerce Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)… The template to customize is [`cart/cart-shipping.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.1/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php)

Comment: are you looking for this functionality on checkout page?

Comment: @aki cart and checkout both.

Comment: @AbuNooh Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in 2023 there is now an option at /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping&section=options to 'Enable the shipping calculator on the basket page'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).